# Does anyone know what this equipment is?

Tags: optics, visible-light, experimental-physics

[image]

[image]

Im a teacher and found this equipment clearing out my science storage room. Any idea what it is used for? Thanks!

Comment: http://antiquescientificgadgets.com/griffin_george_ltd_spectroscope_with_diffraction_gratings_prism_as_picture.html

Comment: A Google search of the manufacturer may turn up something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a spectroscope.  Perhaps one for use with a diffrecation grating rather than a prism.

Comment: One sees the grating.

Comment: yes the light brownish parts are likely graduated in degrees to measure angles.